# Return 444 if https port(443) accesed via http

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx and trying to port my app from Apache, I did google and gone through docs unfortunately not able to achieve below requirement.

If user access website for e.g. http://www.example.com:443 then I would like to return 444, as of now nginx default 400 error page is returned. "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

```
server block -
server {
    listen 1.1.1.1:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What for? No real user or bot will go to port 443 using http protocol. Unless you put that wrong URL somewhere. In that case just fix it

Comment: Right Alexey no real user will go, we want to do that for destructive users as in this case default error page is returned revealing server and version which we want to hide. Somehow I am not able to catch to atleast return custom 400 page or 444

Comment: What you want is meaningless. You could use `server_tokens` directive to hide version. I see no reason to hide server. BTW, you need to catch error 497 http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#errors

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexey for pointing to 497, my main intention was to send custom page rather then default. Is there a way to override error pages in general not specific to any virtual server so that those are returned instead of default nginx pages for uncaught cases.